# Remove the last Comma from a string (PHP / Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

I am generating a list of the terms on a custom post type in Wordpress, in this code i add a comma to the end of each item to separate it in a list format, how would i either eliminate the last the comma from propagating on addition or remove the last comma on the list.

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'clients' );
if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) :
$clients_list = array();
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $clients_list[] = $term->name;
}
$clients = join( ", ", $clients_list );
$catTags .= "$clients, ";
endif;
```

I have tried the following to no success;

```
<em><?php $string = $catTags;
    echo preg_replace("/\,$/","",$catTags); ?></em>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing last comma in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376171/removing-last-comma-in-php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do simply:

```
rtrim($catTags, ', ');
```

Comment: You do need ', ' instead of ',' because you have an extra space at the end of the string. I've just corrected it.

Comment: thanks, wordpress was generating a space after the , that worked fine thanks ! :D

Comment: i just realised that and deleted my previous comment haha :D

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do, is to add a comma at the begin of a loop, by checking if there is already data in the variable.

So in this case something like this:

```
if (strlen($catTags) > 0)
    $catTags .= ',';
```

Comment: So you are calculating the string's length at each iteration? I think it is better to build it with an array, then just join the items with the separator.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

return substr($string, 0, -strlen(','));

will remove the last comma at the end of the string.