# Print in foreach with comma

Tags: php, printing, view

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Removing last comma in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376171/removing-last-comma-in-php)

So I have the following code:

```
<?php
 foreach ($movie->Genres as $genre):
?>
<a href="some_dinamic_link"><?=$genre->name?></a>, 
<?php
endforeach;
?>
```

And this will give me the following: **Action, Drama, Crime,** but I don't need this last comma separator - so my question is what would be the best way to avoid that comma ?

Ps.
If that matters I have 4 loops like this one on my page - for actors, directors, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write you A-tags to an array and join the items.

```
<?php
 $items = array();
 foreach ($movie->Genres as $genre):
  $items[] = '<a href="some_dinamic_link">' . $genre->name . '</a>';
 endforeach;
 echo join(', ', $items);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$temp = array();
foreach($movie->Genres as $genre) {
   $temp[] = <<<EOL
<a href="some_dinamic_link">{$genre->name}</a>
EOL;
}

echo implode(',', $temp);
```

The other option is to use string concatenation, then a substring to delete the trailing comma:

```
$temp = '';
foreach(...) {
   $temp .= ...
}
echo rtrim($temp, ',');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = array();

foreach ( $movie->Genres as $v ){
        $a[] = '<a href="some_link">' . $v->name . '</a>';
}

$s = implode(',', $a);

var_dump($s);
```