# Remove last comma in an anchor

Tags: php

I have this list of anchor tags with comma generate by a foreach loop, for example:

```
<a href="#">Test,</a>
<a href="#">Test1,</a>
<a href="#">Test2,</a>
<a href="#">Test3,</a>
```

This is the code:

```
<?php
foreach ($related['fundings'] as $investor) {
?>
    <a href="<?php echo startup_url($investor['slug']); ?>"><?php echo $investor['name']; ?>,</a>
<?php
}
?>
```

How can I remove the comma in the last anchor tag?

Comment: How about you show us the code that generates this?

Comment: Please post the code that generates said result, and explain what you've tried to accomplish this on your own.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing last comma in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7376171/removing-last-comma-in-php)

Comment: Well, change `<?php echo $investor['name']; ?>,` to `<?php echo $investor['name']; ?>` and that's it.

Comment: If you don't need the comma then remove it from the foreach loop, AND show your desire output.

Answer (score 0):

No regex required here, just set up a `DOM` and use string functions:

```
<?php

$data = <<<DATA
<div>
    <a href="#">Test,</a>
    <a href="#">Test1,</a>
    <a href="#">Test2,</a>
    <a href="#">Test3,</a>
    <a href="#">Leave me alone</a>
</div>
DATA;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($data, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$links = $xpath->query("//a");

foreach ($links as $link) {
    if (substr($link->nodeValue, -1) == ',') {
        $link->nodeValue = substr($link->nodeValue, 0, -1);
    }
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
?>
```

See it working on [**ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/nJbLWd).

---

Or, even simpler, as per your comment, change the code to:

```
<?php echo $investor['name']; ?>
```

instead of `<?php echo $investor['name']; ?>,` (see the comma in the end???).

Answer (score 0):

> If you want to remove comma(,) from only the last anchor tag, you can
>   get the total items in the array and check for last item and remove
>   the comma(,) from that. Below code may help you
>
> ```
> <?php
>  $total = count($related['fundings']);
>  $i=1;
>  foreach ($related['fundings'] as $investor) {     if($i!=$total) {
>  ?>
>   <a href="<?php echo startup_url($investor['slug']); ?>"><?php echo $investor['name']; ?>,</a>
> <?php       }       else    {?>
>  <a href="<?php echo startup_url($investor['slug']); ?>"><?php echo $investor['name']; ?></a>       <?php }
> $i++;}
> ?>
> ```